# What could have caused this question to be sent to the reopen queue?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-reopen

I noticed [a question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203609/does-albus-dumbledore-possibly-have-dementia-or-some-type-of-amnesia-from-overus) had gotten reviewed earlier today, but I can't figure out what prompted the review. The question was asked almost a week ago, on January 17th at 10:16.

[image: Screenshot of asked timestamp]

It was [reviewed and closed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close/140091) within a half hour:

[image: Screenshot of close review]

4-5 hours after that [it got a reopen vote](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48553504#48553504):

[image: Screenshot of chat message saying that a user voted to reopen]

This caused it to go to the reopen queue where [it was reviewed and left closed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/140101):

[image: Screenshot of reopen review]

Another ~4 hours after that it got a second reopen vote, from me:

[image: Screenshot of reopen vote]

All this was still on January 17th.

Then, earlier today (January 22nd) it was [reviewed again in the reopen queue](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/140387):

[image: Screenshot of reopen review earlier today]

There have been no new reopen votes or edits to the question [since January 17th](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/203609/timeline):

[image: Screenshot of post timeline]

Shog's [authoritative answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256071/390967) states:

> There are three ways a question can end up in Reopen Review:
>
> 1. A reopen vote is cast when there are no other *active* reopen votes on the question. Note that this allows for a single question to be enqueued multiple times, provided all votes age away before another one is cast.
> 2. A body edit is made within 5 days of the question being closed by someone who *didn't* vote to reopen. This allows for a single question to be enqueued multiple times, but only *once for each time the question is closed*.
> 3. The question gets popular, for a definition of "popular" based on votes and views. This can only trigger review *once for the life of the question*.

This question does not appear to fulfill any of these criteria. It has no new reopen votes or edits since the last review, and with a score of -10 and only 160 views I don't think it would be considered popular.

What could have prompted this latest review?

The only notable thing that did happen is that the first reopen vote aged away. As you can see, my reopen vote is the only one remaining:

[image: Screenshot of reopen vote count]

[A helpful moderator noted](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48631143#48631143) that the other vote aged away right around the time the review was generated:

[image: Screenshot of moderator's chat message]

Is it possible that the vote aging away caused the question to be sent to the review queue? What else might have happened to cause this?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I've seen, close and reopen review tasks are generated by a scheduled job.

It's possible that the job that generates the review tasks is simple and checks based on the *current* status of the question, rather than going back into the timeline to check what times votes were cast or aged, or when edits were made, etc. In other words, plain and simple criteria that generally work.

The job probably saw that there was only *one* active reopen vote, which was cast after the last review task had already completed. So it assumed that someone had cast a new reopen vote, and generated a new review task.

Comment: i can confirm from my experience that the delay for creating a review item is 10 minutes, by an automated script (i.e. scheduled job)

Comment: Not sure if I understand this. Are you saying that the "job" got delayed for 4+ days and then just happened to initiate right when the first reopen vote aged away, which then enabled it to get confused by the one reopen vote?

Comment: @Alex I edited my answer.

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog What accounts for the timing, though?