# What causes "The community is reviewing whether to reopen this question as of"?

Tags: support, review

I noticed [a closed post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312348) today that apparently has not been edited nor has any pending reopen votes, but shows the message:

> The community is reviewing whether to reopen this question as of X hours ago.

[image]

I checked [the workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH5x7.png) and apparently for a post to enter the reopen queue it's required that: *"Post receives significant edit or vote to reopen?"* The Help Center articles suggest the same [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) and [What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

So what caused this post to enter the reopen queue (I am assuming it's being reviewed)? I'm also asking because there are currently no textual occurrences for the quoted banner message on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22The+community+is+reviewing+whether%22) or [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22The+community+is+reviewing+whether%22).

The closest thing to a possible explanation I've found is [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369493) by Glorfindel. I just searched through the [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release) but it's not obvious what happened in this case.

Comment: may I ask how you pixelated the text in the screenshot? It looks... interesting

Comment: @JamesA see https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Pixellate-Images-Easily/

Answer (score 9):

If you hover over the '9 hours ago' it will tell you the exact timestamp:

[image]

which coincides with the timestamp the Close Votes review queue item was invalidated according to the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17312348/timeline):

[image]

(the question was closed by users outside the review queue). As you suspected, there is a [pending review item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/30270492). *mumbles something about Meta effect*

Some possible causes:

- the question is so [popular](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256071/295232) that it automatically qualifies for the Reopen Votes review queue (found by @Sonic)
- somebody voted to reopen it but later [retracted their vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193061/295232); that may or may not lead to the Reopen Votes review item to be invalidated though

Stack Overflow moderators might be able to confirm via the moderator timeline.

Comment: In this case -unless I'm mistaken- there's another possible explanation for the invalidated close vote review queue item: The post enters the queue after the 1st close vote if enough time passes between the 1st and 3rd close vote. But that still doesn't explain the pending banner message, and if someone cast and retracted a reopen vote the banner message should be updated...

Comment: Questions are also added to the reopen queue immediately upon closure if they trip a threshold for being "popular", based on their score or that of the top answer. I strongly believe that's what happened here, but an SO mod needs to confirm.

Comment: The phrasing of point 3 in Shog's post *"gets popular"* is still confusing. Is that present tense - as in the question **is** popular at time of closure? Or future tense, as in question **gets** popular sometime after closure? Or both? I think these rules should be grouped together in one place, otherwise users spend time searching and wondering.